# Proof for the product of the solutions for the equation

Tags: logarithms

Proof that the product of the solutions for the equation:
  $ x^{\log_{2016} x}   \times \sqrt{2016} = x^{2016}$
is natural number. Find the digit of the units for that number.

I started by taking log with base 2016 on both sides:
$ \log_{2016} ({x^{\log_{2016} x}}\times \sqrt{2016}) = \log_{2016}x^{2016}$
$ \log_{2016} x^{\log_{2016}x}+\log_{2016} \sqrt{2016}=2016\times log_{2016} x$
$ \log_{2016} x \times \log_{2016} x + log_{2016} 2016^ \frac{1}{2}=2016\times log_{2016} x$
$\log^{2}_{2016} x - 2016\times log_{2016} x + \log_{2016} 2016^\frac{1}{2}=2016\times \log_{2016}x$
$log^{2}_{2016} x - 2016\times log_{2016} x + \frac{1}{2}=0  /\times 2$
$2log^{2}_{2016} x - 4032\times log_{2016} x+ 1=0$
Then I did the change: $ \log_{2016} x=y$
$2y^{2} -4032\times y +1=0.$
But the solutions and their product are not a natural number and I can't find what's incorrect in this. Can you correct it?

Comment: To find the product of all $x$'s we need to find the sum of all $y$'s, not the product.

Answer (score 1):

taking the logarithm on both sides we can write
$$\ln(x^{\log_{2016}x})+\ln\sqrt{2016}=2016\ln(x)$$
and
simplifying further
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2016)}\ln(x)+\ln\sqrt{2016}=2016\ln(x)$$
and you will got a quadratic equation in $\ln(x)$

Comment: I have that the product of the two solutions for the quadratic equation (by x) is $2016^{2016}$. The unit of the units od that number is 6, isn't it?

Comment: yes i think this is right

Comment: Thank you for the help! The digit of the units for that number*..I'm sorry for the errors in the  previous comment.